# Cumulative distribution function of the supremum of $U[0,\theta]$ for $\theta \in [0,1]$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $U_{\theta} \sim U[0,\theta]$ (with every independent of every other) and $X = \sup_{\theta \in [0,1]} U_{\theta}$. Now what is $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x)$?

My attempt:
$\mathbb{P}(U_{\theta} \leq x) = \frac{x}{\theta}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(\forall_{\theta \in [0,1]} \ U_{\theta} \leq x)$ therefore $\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = \prod_{\theta\in[0,1]} \mathbb{P}(U_{\theta} \leq x) = \prod_{\theta\in[0,1]} \frac{x}{\theta}$.

Firstly I am not sure if that product is "legal" secondly if the equality even is correct. But assuming it is I would want to calculate it more accurately. To achieve this we take $n$ evenly spaced samples from $[0,1]$, so $\{ \frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n},\dots, \frac{n}{n}\}$ and taking the limit of $n \to \infty$. Resulting in:
$$\mathbb{P(X \leq x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{\frac{x}{\frac{i}{n} } } = \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{n}{i} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^nn^n}{n!} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(x \cdot \frac{n}{n!^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)^n } = \cases{0 \; \text{if} \;x \in (-\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{e}) \\ 1 \; \text{if} \;x  = \frac{1}{e} \\ \text{undefined else}}$$

Which is clearly incorrect as $\mathbb{P}(X \leq 1) = 1$ (since all are smaller than 1). I am also not sure of if you these evenly spaced samples would work (as there are properties such as being algebraic which holds for all numbers in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not for all in $\mathbb{R}$).

My second idea would be to take the integral over all $\theta$ or something like that, but I couldn't figure it out.

Lastly if you have some literature recommendations which might help me in understanding similar problems, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You could write $U_\theta$ as $\theta V$, where $V$ is $U(0,1)$. What is the sup now?

Comment: You only specify the distribution of each  $U_\theta$, but not how the different $U_\theta$ are related. Your question is thus not well-posed.

Comment: @Galton The only conclusion I have been able to draw so far is $\sup_{\theta \in [0,1]} U_{\theta} = \sup_{\theta \in [0,1]} \theta U[0,1] \leq (\sup_{\theta \in [0,1]} \theta)\sup_{\theta \in [0,1]} U[0,1] = \sup_{\theta \in [0,1]} U[0,1] \leq 1$. The last conclusion is because when taking an infinite amount of draws (even uncountable) the maximum is of course going to be 1. So I atleast know the answer makes sense (because the probability is less or equal to 1).

Comment: @PhoemueX Ah thank you didn't think of that, I edited it, if there are more issues let me know.

Comment: If we interpret $U_\theta$ as $\theta V$, then $\sup_{\theta} U_{\theta} = V \sup_\theta \theta = V$, so your variable has a standard uniform distribution. Notice that $\theta \mapsto \theta V$ is highly dependent. If you want to view this as a stochastic process $\theta\mapsto U_\theta$ indexed on a continuum where the $U_\theta$ are somehow independent, then this is asking more than I can do and you most likely generated an ill-posed problem. This is probably also why @PhoemueX asked how the $U_\theta$ are related.

Comment: @Galton The second thing is what I meant, still thank you for your response.

Comment: @Galton Thank you for rephrasing my question better. I searched for "continuum of stochastic variables" and now I might have found an article that gives me more insight!

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made was that the CDF of $U_{\theta}$ actually isn't $\frac{x}{\theta}$ but actually
$$
\mathbb{P}(U_{\theta} \leq x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x \leq 0 \\
\frac{x}{\theta} & \text{if } x \in [0,\theta] \\
 1 & \text{else}\\
\end{cases}
$$

The answer is
$$\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < 1 \\
1 & \text{else }\\
\end{cases}$$

because for any $x < 1$ we can find infinite $\theta > x + \epsilon$ for some $1 > \epsilon > 0$ and therefore $\mathbb{P}(U_{\theta} \leq x \text{ for all } \theta > x + \epsilon) \leq \epsilon^n$ for any $n \geq 1.$